# Update GNOME Shell brightness slider automatically on brightness change

Tags: power-management, gnome-shell, brightness

Up till GNOME 3.22, [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/947/dim-on-battery-power/) works, but on GNOME 3.24 it doesn't. I would like to set a different brightness level for plugged-in and on-battery states, which I can do with the following command:-

```
echo BRIGHTNESS_LEVEL > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

I can put this in a udev rule and it works, but the brightness slider on the GNOME Shell system menu does not change to reflect the new level. The changed brightness level is properly shown in the Power settings panel, so it seems that the problem is with the Shell itself. I also tried using `gsd-backlight-helper`, but it too has the same result. Is there a way to update the brightness slider on the Shell's menu on adjusting the brightness programmatically like this? (I would like to avoid using things like `xdotool` to simulate input, etc.)

PS: I also tried `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage 50` but it says that the `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon` object/path is not provided/does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I know. Procrastinating, perhaps! :-P Anyway, I was wondering if there's a workaround to use in the meantime.

Comment: An [issue] (https://github.com/nailfarmer/gnome-shell-dim-on-battery-extension/issues/8) is already raised at the extension's GitHub site. I also tried adding `3.24` to `metadata.json` and disabling extension version validation, to no avail. On the other hand, the `StepDown`/`StepUp` methods don't work either. In every case I get the message: `Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files`. It works on GNOME 3.22 but it seems that `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon` is no longer available in GNOME 3.24.

Comment: I have filed a [bug report] (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781780).